# Python xarray groupby not creating correct groups

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I'm trying to create weekly groups using xarray groupy based on a datetime64 time dimension. For some reason it is creating extra groups and putting some dates in the wrong groups. I'm using the `S` coordinate to group by weeks. For each year there should be five weekly groups, but it is creating seven groups.

Groups being created:

```
In [38]: em.groupby('S.week').groups                                                                                         
Out[38]: 
{1: [1, 6, 10, 15, 20, 25, 31, 35, 40, 45, 50, 56, 61, 65, 70, 75, 80, 86, 90],
 2: [2, 7, 11, 16, 21, 26, 32, 36, 41, 46, 51, 57, 62, 66, 71, 76, 81, 87, 91],
 3: [3, 8, 12, 17, 22, 27, 33, 37, 42, 47, 52, 58, 63, 67, 72, 77, 82, 88, 92],
 4: [4, 9, 13, 18, 23, 28, 34, 38, 43, 48, 53, 59, 64, 68, 73, 78, 83, 89, 93],
 5: [14, 19, 24, 29, 39, 44, 49, 54, 69, 74, 79, 84, 94],
 52: [5, 60],
 53: [0, 30, 55, 85]}
```

information on `em`:

```
In [39]: em                                                                                                                  
Out[39]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (S: 95, latitude: 181, lead: 32, longitude: 360)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 -90.0 -89.0 -88.0 -87.0 ... 88.0 89.0 90.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 ... 356.0 357.0 358.0 359.0
  * lead       (lead) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 12:00:00 ... 31 days 12:00:00
  * S          (S) datetime64[ns] 1999-01-02 1999-01-09 ... 2017-01-30
Data variables:
    eto        (S, lead, latitude, longitude) float64 dask.array<shape=(95, 32, 181, 360), chunksize=(1, 32, 181, 360)>
```

Values for `S`:

```
In [35]: em.S                                                                                                                
Out[35]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'S' (S: 95)>
array(['1999-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '1999-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1999-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1999-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1999-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2000-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2000-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2002-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2002-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2002-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2002-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2002-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2003-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2003-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2003-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2003-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2003-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2006-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2006-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2006-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2006-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2006-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2007-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2007-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2007-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2007-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2007-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2008-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2008-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2008-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2008-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2008-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2009-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2009-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2009-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2009-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2009-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2011-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2011-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2011-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2011-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2011-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2012-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2012-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2012-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2012-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2012-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2013-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2013-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2014-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2014-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-01-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-01-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-01-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-01-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-01-30T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * S        (S) datetime64[ns] 1999-01-02 1999-01-09 ... 2017-01-23 2017-01-30
```

So, for example, group `53` should all actually be in group `1`, and then others are in the wrong group. All of the group `53` dates:

```
In [40]: em.S[0].values                                                                                                      
Out[40]: numpy.datetime64('1999-01-02T00:00:00.000000000')

In [41]: em.S[5].values                                                                                                      
Out[41]: numpy.datetime64('2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000000')

In [42]: em.S[10].values                                                                                                     
Out[42]: numpy.datetime64('2001-01-02T00:00:00.000000000')

In [43]: em.S[55].values                                                                                                     
Out[43]: numpy.datetime64('2010-01-02T00:00:00.000000000')

In [44]: em.S[85].values                                                                                                     
Out[44]: numpy.datetime64('2016-01-02T00:00:00.000000000')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The groups are determined according to `em.S.dt.week`. I think the this follows ISO 8601 and 1. Jan. can be in week 53; check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that it is actually putting same dates into different groups. There are a total of 19 dates that have January 2 and they are being split up into different groups. That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why do you think the week attribution is wrong?

Comment: Because it is putting same month-day dates (e.g., January 2 for all years) into different groups. How is that correct? Am I missing something? They should all be in the same weekly group, right?

Comment: Ok, @mathause is correct about the ISO weeks. It turns out the same day-month can be in different ISO weeks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you could do, however, is to define your own weeks. For example: `week = em.S.dt.dayofyear // 7 + 1` and use this `em.groupby(week)`

Comment: I think this what I'm looking for, @mathause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groups being created are not actually wrong, as pointed out by several already. I was expecting that each weekly group would have the same month-days, but that is not the case since groups are based on [ISO weeks](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020). So, January 2 can actually be in week 1, 52, or 53 based on ISO weeks.